# Jenkins error "No such property: docker for class: groovy.lang.Binding"

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.coding-stories.com/blog/2015/08/23/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-workflow-and-docker/) to create a simple docker environment in as part of my Jenkins pipeline build.

I'm trying to build a couple of Docker images just as a test before I do my maven build.  At the moment I have the following Groovy for my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
#!groovy

node {

  stage 'Building docker env'
  def dbImage = docker.build('oracle', 'docker/oracle')
  def wlpImage = docker.build('liberty', 'docker/liberty')


  stage 'Running maven build'
  git url: 'https://mysite/myproject.git', branch: 'docker'
  def mvnHome = tool 'maven 3.3.9'
  sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B clean install"
}
```

I'm trying to have the Docker build look in the directory "docker/oracle" and call the `Dockerfile` in that directory, and build the Docker images named `oracle`, and `liberty`.  At the moment though it's giving me this error:

```
Running on master in /root/.jenkins/workspace/pipeline_test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (Building docker env)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage Building docker env
Proceeding
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: docker for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
...
```

Any ideas what could be the problem with the `docker build` command I'm using? (or could it be something I forgot to install in Jenkins?)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The issue was I needed to install the [Docker Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) in Jenkins.

---

To install the plugin using the GUI:

`Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Available (tab) > docker-workflow`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have this issue:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: docker for class: groovy.lang.Binding.

We most likely encountered the same issue, in order to fix it I only had to install the **Docker Pipeline plugin** in Jenkins, so all you have to do is go to:

**Jenkins Homepage > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Available**

Search for **Docker Pipeline** install it restart jenkins and you are ready to go.

For more info about **Docker Pipeline Plugin Scripts** click [here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing some part of your code, but where do you define the docker? If that's the complete Groovy script, you're trying to bind a variable which isn't declared anything, so it's not to weird that it fails, right?

Just define a docker it that's what you want, like:

```
def docker = "my docker" // something similar like this
```

And it will at-least resolve your missing property exception.

Whenever we see the error like below :

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:
```

It means , groovey script did not able to find the property mentioned post the colon sign ***:*** , so we need to either define the user defined variable/property or use the correct one from API.

Comment: If you read the tutorial I linked, it explains: "The CloudBees Docker Workflow Plugin provides a global variable docker which offers access to the common Docker functions in workflow scripts."

Answer (score 2):

As Pete says you will have to install the [Docker Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow). You can do that though the Jenkins UI.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It should have been a comment to that other answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but after I installed the Docker Pipeline plugin as @Affes Salem suggested it is working now.